# Why when i booting my archlinux i already have opened terminal windows

Tags: linux, arch-linux

When i boot my archlinux it has already opened 3 terminal windows and some folders (from my one of the last session)). It kinda saved my one session programs and stuck with it. How to fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you also include which desktop environment you use with arch?